# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10025.0'

Tags: python, pandas

```
COD_CUST  
 10025.0   
 10761.0  
 10869.0    
 12361.0
```

trying to convert the above column into integer as below:

```
mser_offus['COD_CUST']=mser_offus['COD_CUST'].astype(int)
```

but getting the ***following error:***

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10025.0'

Comment: Do you need remove `.0` only and cast to int?

Comment: need to remove .0

Answer (score 0):

IIUC if need remove all values after `.` and convert to `int`:

```
df['COD_CUST'] = df['COD_CUST'].astype(float).astype(int)
print (df)
   COD_CUST
0     10025
1     10761
2     10869
3     12361
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use, print (int(float(COD_CUST)))